# PHP Autoload - File Found - Class Fatal Error

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces, autoload

I have a function on load that checks a users login status.  Here is a small chunk of the code...

```
//
// user is logged in, get user info
$user = Model\User::getByKey($_COOKIE['ukey']);
if($user->field('id') >= 1 || !isset($status)) {
    //
    // establish google connection
    Classes\Google\Google::construct($user->field('id'), $user->field('ga_account'));

...
```

I have an __autoload function which finds the path of the file perfectly fine.  However, I get a fatal error because the "\Classes\Google\Google"  class is not found.

new Google() ... is   located at /classes/google/google.class.php.  The file is there, the autload function has the correct file path but why isn't the class found?

I do not have any namespacing on this particular Google() class file. This is all custom built, not a third party framework.

Answer (score 1):

1- use class_exists to make sure class is loaded . 
2- if class not loaded , in google.class.php make a die , so u'll know file loaded or not.
3- if class loaded , make a new object here . the test it , so u can find the class definition is true or not.

Comment: I am using the php function called __autoload.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php  So this function finds my google.class.php file, loads it with require_once but than rest of my script fails when trying to call Google().